# How to use JOGL's NEWT model to create a window in Mac OS X

Tags: java, opengl, nsview, nswindow, jogl

At work I am creating a music visualization program. JOGL was chosen because we needed an API to program 3D graphics and have it work on multiple platforms right away. At the moment, I am using GLCanvas to render all the work, however, the downside is that it uses the EDT to render the OpenGL loop and the EDT is also used to dispatch other GUI interactions. Therefore, if I make the renderer sleep for a certain amount of time in order to wait on a data structure or control the FPS, then I make the whole EDT sleep and therefore slow down the GUI.

What I want to do is have the music player (on one thread) interact with data structures the visualizer is using. I would do this by having 2 synchronized methods that notify the other thread or wait themselves, depending on what's happening. The problem with what I just mentioned is that at the moment the program is implemented where the EDT runs the rendering (this is what happens with GLCanvas). In this case, when the rendering loop (EDT Thread) goes to retrieve an empty data structure, it is told to wait. The thread will wait until a song is loaded then played, however, I cannot load a song using the GUI because the EDT thread is waiting until a song is loaded and played but a song cannot be loaded because the EDT is a sleep. Essentially, this is a dead lock.

I apologize for all the writing. I hope I am making this easy to read.
A perfect solution to my problem is to use JOGL's NEWT, which will run the rendering loop on a separate thread then the EDT separately. This will allow me to sleep the rendering thread and the music player thread back and forth while not touching the EDT, which handles all over GUI interactions.

Before I incorporate NEWT into the actual project, I just want to try basic things with NEWT such as opening a window on Mac OS 10.7. So I created a project that just opens a window and it fails. The code to do so is (well one way to do it, this is the only code in my project):

```
Display display = NewtFactory.createDisplay(null); 
GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2)); 
Screen screen = NewtFactory.createScreen(display, 0); 
Window window = NewtFactory.createWindow(screen, capabilities); 
window.setVisible(true);
```

or:

```
GLProfile.initSingleton(true);
GLProfile glp = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);;
GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
Renderer r = new Renderer();
GLWindow window = GLWindow.create(caps);
window.addGLEventListener(r);
window.setSize(300, 300);
window.setTitle("NEWT Window Test");
window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowDestroyNotify(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
});
Animator a = new FPSAnimator(window);
a.start();
window.setVisible(true);
```

No matter what way I use, I still get the same errors, which are:

1. Located in the console, it says:

Detected screen size 1280x800
createWindow0 - Parent is neither NSWindow nor NSView : 0x0
*************** viewWillDraw: 0x0x7f9ca062ae18Invalid memory access of location 0x248 rip=0x10df02478

1. A Window opens saying:
   NEWTTRY quit unexpectedly while using the libnewt.jnilib plug-in

I have searched the internet for days and extensively read the NEWT API which is poorly documented. I hope someone can help because using NEWT in high performance programs is extremely beneficial and more flexible than using GLCanvas.

I am using:

OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7 (11A511)
Report Version:  9
Model: MacBook5,1, BootROM MB51.007D.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.40f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
The most recent Java update for Mac 
jogl-2.0-b23-20110303-macosx

Answer (score 0):

This is the tutorial I used to learn the newt operations https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-2.

It explains the Newt as well as the JFrame setup.